# TYPO3 SURF Fatal Error: Extension key ... is NOT loaded

Tags: deployment, typo3, typoscript

I use Typo3 SURF as deployment tool. Every time I deploy I get this error:

```
 TYPO3 Fatal Error: Extension key "backend" is NOT loaded!
```

It seems to be a caching issue even tho the typo3temp folder has proper permissions. I can also load the website once after deployment, if I reload it again the fatal error shows up...

Here is the configuration of my surf file:

```
    <?php
/** @var $deployment \TYPO3\Surf\Domain\Model\Deployment */



$application = new \TYPO3\Surf\Application\TYPO3\CMS('test-stage');
$application->setOption('repositoryUrl', 'git@git.test.de:test/test_deploy.git');
$application->setOption('composerCommandPath', 'composer');
$application->setOption('applicationRootDirectory', 'Web');
$application->setOption('keepReleases', 5);
$application->setOption('context', 'Testing');
$application->setDeploymentPath('/var/www/test-stage');


$workflow = new \TYPO3\Surf\Domain\Model\SimpleWorkflow();
$workflow->addTask('\TYPO3\\Surf\\Task\\TYPO3\\CMS\\FlushCachesTask', 'switch', $application);


$workflow->defineTask('test:repairpermissions',
    \TYPO3\Surf\Task\ShellTask::class,
    array('command' => 'sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/test-stage/releases/current/vendor;'.
        'sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/test-stage/releases/current/web;')
);

$deployment->onInitialize(function() use ($workflow, $application) {
    $workflow->addTask('test:repairpermissions', 'cleanup', $application);
    //$workflow->removeTask(\TYPO3\Surf\Task\Neos\Flow\SetFilePermissionsTask::class);
});

$node = new \TYPO3\Surf\Domain\Model\Node('test');
$node->setHostname('test.cloudapp.net');
$node->setOption('username', 'test');

$application->addNode($node);

$deployment->addApplication($application);
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't have any extensions installed. If you have `typo3_console` as extension try running it with the command `install:generatepackagestates` on the remote server.

More things you can see here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/typo3_console/CommandReference/Index.html#install-generatepackagestates

Comment: I tried running install:generatepackagestates and I got this error: #1382276561: The package "fluid_styled_slider" depends on "fluid_styled_content" which is not present in the system.

Comment: You have to add all extensions you need to use and to install either by requiring in composer or by adding them as parameter to the command. See the documentation link I posted.